# How a cryptocurrency like MATIC works?

Tags: tokens, ether, polygon

I’m a beginner to the cryptocurrency and I’m struggling to understand the fundamentals of this field. I was reading about how cryptos work and what they are used for. I took as an example the MATIC and I couldn’t really understand:

“Polygon (MATIC) is an Ethereum token that powers the Polygon Network — a protocol and framework for building and connecting Ethereum-compatible blockchain networks.”

How does it power the network? I have seen this concept so many times. In other words, how a cryptocurrency powers a network? I understand this might be a silly question to ask but I searched a lot but couldn’t really get it. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Polygon and several other project created a blockchain that runs independently of Ethereum. It just happen that their native currency also is a token in Ethereum. They provide a bridge to move tokens between both chains.

The term "powered by" is just a marketing strategy. The side chain, or L2 chain is usually an Ethereum clone that uses proof of authority or proof of stake as consensus algorithm.